# jQuery foreach loop for ajax dosent get break via return false

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, loops, break

I'm trying to upload multiple images via ajax with foreach loop to stop memory limit error. So below code segment runs as I wanted but I can't break the loop if its return errors. What I have done here is assign false via ajax error function and then return it. So the loop should be a break. But it isn't working as it should be. If I `console.log(noErrors)` at error function it print false. But after error function it return true again. I don't know why this happens.  Please help

```
 var selectedFiles = $('input[name="img_path[]"]')[0].files;

                var i = 1;
                var noErrors = true;
                $.each(selectedFiles, function (index, value) {

                    var form_data = new FormData();
                    form_data.append('image', value);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "{{route('supplier.project-add-images-ajax')}}",
                        data: form_data,
                        method: 'post',
                        cache: false,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,

                        success: function (response) {
                            console.log(selectedFiles.length);
                            /*  if (i == selectedFiles.length) {
                                  alert(1);
                              }*/
                        },

                        error: function (response) {
                            $.post("{{route('supplier.project-remove-temp-directory')}}");
                            alert('Each image shouldn\'t exceed 1mb');
                            noErrors = false;
                        },
                    });

                    return noErrors;

                });
```

I also tried this but it also not working. Calling for a function which returns false out of ajax call

```
 error: function (response) {
                            returnFalse();
                            $.post("{{route('supplier.project-remove-temp-directory')}}");
                            alert('Each image shouldn\'t exceed 1mb');

                        }
```

This will return false

```
function returnFalse(){
                        return false;
                    }
```

Comment: For me i would prepare the need parameters, so i can only execute AJAX once.

Comment: In here I can't do that since I need to upload each file per each time

Comment: Try putting a `console.log("Starting", index);` before the `$.ajax` line, and you will see that those are all logged before any of them complete with either the `success` or the `error` callback, because the `success` and `error` callbacks are called at some point in the future.  Your loop will not wait for them.  To fix it, you can launch the first request, and only launch the second request in the `success` callback.

Comment: @user2740650 thanks for the comment could you please help me to fix this with my code

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var selectedFiles = $('input[name="img_path[]"]')[0].files;

    $.each(selectedFiles, function (index, value) {
        if (upload(value) === false) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    function upload(value) {
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('image', value);

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('supplier.project-add-images-ajax')}}",
            data: form_data,
            method: 'post',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,

            success: function (response) {
                console.log(selectedFiles.length);
                /*  if (i == selectedFiles.length) {
                      alert(1);
                  }*/
            },

            error: function (response) {
                $.post("{{route('supplier.project-remove-temp-directory')}}");
                alert('Each image shouldn\'t exceed 1mb');
                return false;
            },
        });
    }
```